# Get error when coding Python in Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, pydev

I was looking for an appropriate Python IDE for a long time. When googling and looking for a desired one in this forum and on the other websites I finally realised Eclipse is being suggested by the majority of the professional programmers. So as you would understand I downloaded Eclipse and the Pydev plugin for that purpose and started trying to configure and prepare Eclipse for usage and programming. As a beginner and a new one to Python, frankly I faced so many serious obstacles for installing and configuring the Eclipse and specifically for installing the Pydev plugin. After so much struggle, I finally succeeded in getting through with the configuration and installation but when I run the Eclipse and try to build a new project, when I introduce a new module and code, when I debug and run my code I get such error "

"Exception occurred executing command line.

```
Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Python3\python.exe" (in directory "C:\EclipseWorkspace\csse120\Hello world"): CreateProcess error=3, The system cannot find the path specified"
```

I looked for Identical or similar issues in the forum and topics but the only suggestions were that this might be due to python 3.0(means I should be choosing Python 2.6 or 2.7 while choosing a new project), but this didn't solve my problem.

Would anybody please assist me: what should I be doing to solve this issue and problem. I be appreciating and thankful toward ant guidance and assistance.

I Thank you all in advance for your kind help

Comment: Hi. thanks a lot for your answer. Yesterday, I got a USB that had a suspicious behaviour.I suspected the problem might have been due to that USB flash installing a virus. I installed an antivirus and it detected a virus existing on my hard drive and actually removed it. Seems the virus had restricted access to that directory. Now it seems the problem is almost gone. If the problem persisted anymore, then I will try to ask it again in the forum. I really Thank you so much for your help and hope you luck!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Lots of information in your question is not needed to solve your problem. Try to write to the point questions and if the answer below is correct then accept it.

Comment: If you're getting started in PyDev, make sure you follow the steps at: http://pydev.org/manual_101_root.html

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used eclipse in a while, but normally that error simply means that eclipse can't find the specified file in the specified path. 
it might sounds stupid, I know, but are you sure you have C:\Program Files\Python3\python.exe in your system?